Openresty + Torch. Is it even possible?
I’m trying to use the Torch library in OpenResty, but I’m not having much luck. I’ve attempted to install Torch in the OpenResty Docker container using both Luarocks and manual installation methods, but no matter what I do, I keep getting an error message. Is it even feasible to use Torch with OpenResty? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
The way I use it
location / {
  content_by_lua_block {
    require 'torch'
  }
}

Error
2024/05/10 17:10:42 [error] 2578#2578: *1 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: /usr/local/openresty/luajit/share/lua/5.1/torch/init.lua:13: cannot load '/usr/local/openresty/luajit/lib/lua/5.1/libtorch.so'
stack traceback:
coroutine 0:
  [C]: in function 'require'
  content_by_lua(/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:23):2: in main chunk, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1"
127.0.0.1 - - [10/May/2024:17:10:42 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 128571 "-" "curl/7.81.0"

Installation via luarocks
git clone https://github.com/torch/cwrap.git
cd cwrap
luarocks make rocks/cwrap-scm-1.rockspec
luarocks install --server=https://luarocks.org/dev torch

Manual installation ('./install.sh' is omitted)
FROM openresty/openresty:jammy

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt update && apt install -y git sudo software-properties-common python3-pip
RUN pip3 install ipython

RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/ppa && \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y qt4-dev-tools libqt4-dev libqtcore4 libqtgui4 


RUN git clone https://github.com/torch/distro.git ~/torch --recursive
WORKDIR root/torch
RUN sed -i 's/python-software-properties/software-properties-common/g' install-deps
RUN sed -i 's/unzip gnuplot gnuplot-x11 ipython/unzip gnuplot gnuplot-x11/g' ./install-deps

RUN ["/bin/bash", "install-deps"]

